# Height of colorbox

Tags: color, boxes, height

I'm trying to "highlight" two parts of a sentence by using a `\colorbox` like so:

```
\colorbox{red}{This is} \colorbox{blue}{a great sentence.}
```

The problem is that in the second part the height colorbox is a bit bigger, because it contains a `g` which extends below the baseline. As a result, the two colorboxes do not align at the bottom which looks suboptimal.

How would I make the two boxes line up?

Comment: @Yiannis: I'm not sure, but I find this a strange tag for the question. Are you going to add this tag to every solution where the `\strut` was the main point?

Comment: @Hendrik Tags trigger related keyword questions. I thought if there were more examples it would be useful.

Comment: @Yiannis: If we had tag support for answers, the tag would be fine there. However, `\strut` is just one possible solution of many, though probably the easiest. I prefer tags which characterize the question (size, alignment) instead of keywords of each good answer (`\strut`, `\rule`, `\vphantom`, `\parbox`, ...). It could be discussed further on meta: [Adding tags to a question in accordance with a provided answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577/adding-tags-to-a-question-in-accordance-with-a-provided-answer).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a `\strut`

```
{\colorbox{red}{\strut This is} \colorbox{blue}{\strut a great sentence.}}
```

LaTeX/TEX define `\strut` to be an invisible box of width zero that extends
just enough above and below the baseline.

Comment: Is it possible to redefine the \strut to be as short as possible based on the current font size?

Comment: @xport It is possible. A `\strut` is simply a rule of zero width for example in plain TeX it is `\vrule height8.5pt depth3.5pt width0pt`.

Comment: but it is not the shortest \strut I think. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I was looking just for this thing!! Great! As a bonus point: "A strut is a structural component designed to resist longitudinal compression. "

Answer (score 15):

Let's compare and decide which one do you prefer :)

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{calc}

%Define a reference depth. 
%You can choose either relative or absolute.
%--------------------------
\newlength{\DepthReference}
\settodepth{\DepthReference}{g}%relative to a depth of a letter.
%\setlength{\DepthReference}{6pt}%absolute value.

%Define a reference Height. 
%You can choose either relative or absolute.
%--------------------------
\newlength{\HeightReference}
\settoheight{\HeightReference}{T}
%\setlength{\HeightReference}{6pt}


%--------------------------
\newlength{\Width}%

\newcommand{\MyColorBox}[2][red]%
{%
    \settowidth{\Width}{#2}%
    %\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \colorbox{#1}%
    {%      
        \raisebox{-\DepthReference}%
        {%
                \parbox[b][\HeightReference+\DepthReference][c]{\Width}{\centering#2}%
        }%
    }%
}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}
\begin{document}

\noindent @Thomas \hrulefill\colorbox{red}{This is} \colorbox{blue}{a great sentence.}\hrulefill

\vspace{5mm}

\noindent @Yiannis \hrulefill{\colorbox{red}{\strut This is} \colorbox{blue}{\strut a great sentence.}}\hrulefill

\vspace{5mm}

\noindent @xport \hrulefill\MyColorBox{This is} \MyColorBox[blue]{a great sentence.}\hrulefill


\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

My idea above can be explained as follows:

1. I choose the tallest letter as a reference for common height.
2. I choose the deepest letter as a reference for common depth.
3. Then a make a parbox with constant height based on the sum of height and depth mentioned in step 1 and 2.
4. Move the parbox down as far as the depth mentioned in step 2.

Comment: @How about a letter with and accent?

Comment: @Yiannis, I have not tried it. I will do soon. Go to have lunch now. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to move the boxes up and down. The baselines should stay aligned in good typography.

Comment: @Hendrik. Yes. I think so.

Comment: You saved my day, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{soul,xcolor}
\sethlcolor{red}
\begin{document}

\hl{This is} \hl{\strut a great sentence.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and convenient solution is to define a custom command for marking text with a color. It takes two arguments, the color and the text to be marked. The coloured box surrounding the text is created with the `adjustbox` package. In order to ensure the box fills the entire line height, we prepend `\strut` to the text.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\marktext}[2]{\adjustbox{bgcolor=#1}{\strut #2}}
```