# Change font size of a paragraph and make all colorbox have equal height

Tags: colorbox

## The context

I know that it is possible to enclose text in colored boxes by using `\colorbox`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
 \colorbox{red}{This} \colorbox{green}{is} \colorbox{red}{a} \colorbox{green}{paragraph}\colorbox{red}{.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also know that it is possible to make all colorboxes to have equal height by using `\strut`. I learned this from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7531) answer at another question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
 \colorbox{red}{\strut This}\colorbox{green}{\strut is}\colorbox{red}{\strut a}\colorbox{green}{\strut paragraph}\colorbox{red}{\strut .}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also know that it is possible to change the font size with `\fontsize`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \fontsize{20pt}{0pt}\selectfont
  This is a paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image]

## The problem

When I change the font size with `\fontsize` and use `\strut`, `\strut` doesn't have the same effect that it has when the font size hasn't been changed. Please see code and screenshot below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \fontsize{20pt}{3pt}\selectfont
  \colorbox{red}{\strut This}\colorbox{green}{\strut is}\colorbox{red}{\strut a}\colorbox{green}{\strut paragraph}\colorbox{red}{\strut .}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## The question

How to change the font size and, at the same time, make all colorboxes have equal height?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

`\fontsize{20pt}{3pt}` specifies letters 20pt high on lines that are 3pt apart, which is doomed to fail.

Use `\fontsize{20pt}{23pt}` to get a 23pt strut rather than a 3pt one.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \fontsize{20pt}{23pt}\selectfont
  \colorbox{red}{\strut This}\colorbox{green}{\strut is}\colorbox{red}{\strut a}\colorbox{green}{\strut paragraph}\colorbox{red}{\strut .}
\end{document}
```